# Twin or not twin

Tags: riddle

A few days ago, I saw two scholars discussing in front of a blackboard.

One scholar said that A and B were twins. The other scholar said that A and C were twins.

So I thought B and C were also twins. But, they said B and C were not twins.

Can you explain it?

Comment: Not a very interesting riddle IMO. Basically just "which non-transitive relation that happens be called *twin* am I thinking of?".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think they are talking about

> [Twin primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime)

In particular

> $A= 5$, $B=3$ or $7$ and $C=7$ or $3$

Comment: if B and C are both 3 or both 7 then they are also technically twins

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "both 3 or both 7".  B and C are two distinct number.  If B= 3 and C= 7 they are both primes but they are NOT twin primes.

Answer (score 15):

They might be talking about

> Twinned cities

For example,

> (A) Nassau, Bahamas; (B) Shanghai, China; and (C) Kish, Iran.
>  (A) is twinned with (B) and (C), but (B) is not twinned with (C).

evidence:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sister_city

Comment: Could you add a Wikipedia link to your spoiler explaining what the term means? (There _definitely_ is one, but I don't want to link it in a comment)

Comment: "Sister Cities" is NOT the same as "Twin Cities"!

Comment: @user247327 Ignoring the spoiler, but, uh, yes, they are? Click the link.

Answer (score 10):

Could they be talking about

> Two completely separate pairs of twins, where the name A happens to be a shared name between two of the twins, one from each pair?

Answer (score 7):

How about

> A = twin 1,  B = twin 2, C = twin 2

Answer (score 4):

Nobody yet mentioned but:

> One of the scholars simply lied. Based himself on incorrect information (if scholar meant as a researcher) or deserved the F (or european 1) grade (if scholar meant as a student)

Answer (score 3):

Easy:

> B and C are the same person

Comment: It seems your answer is identical to Statman's

Comment: @Riley - ah. I didn't understand Statman's answer when I glanced at it first. I can see now that he meant what I said. I'll mark him up.

Answer (score 3):

> A and B are identical twins (related). 
>  A and C are also both teammates on the Minnesota Twins baseball team. 
>  B and C are not related so they are not twins (B is also not a member of the baseball team).

Comment: Now **that's** pretty good!

Answer (score 0):

> At least one of them (let's say B) is indeed a twin, but from a different pair of twins (siblings B and D), but then they meant that B and C are not *mutual* twins. Kind of inconsistent, but that means the scholars were not mathematicians and thus not talking about twin primes...

Answer (score 0):

> B and C are Siamese twins as opposed to JUST twins
> A is the triplet of B and C.
> So A is the twin of B, A is the twin of C, B is the SIAMESE twin of C.
> Splitting hairs/heirs .......... maybe

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you edit your answer to include spoiler tags, so as to avoid spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves? Thanks!

Comment: how is that done?

Comment: Put `>!` at the start of each line, and put an extra line break between every line, otherwise it won't quite work.

Comment: OK I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 solutions, though (2) and (3) make some additional assumptions:

Solution 1

> The puzzle question does not mention that the 2 scholars agreed with each other on the first two statements ("A and B are twins" and "A and C are twins"). So we may assume that the scholars are discussing 3 different entities, A, B and C, and that whether 2 entities are "twins" in their subject of expertise is not a straight-forward to infer (so they are still hypothesizing), or alternatively that concept may have been poorly defined and so is subjective. The 2 scholars are researching the relationship between the 3 entities and currently they both agree only the relationship between B and C, but differ on the relationship between A and the remaining two entities.

Solution 2

> A, B and C are 3 conjoined infants, with A and B being joined together and A and C being joined together at birth but B and C were not joined. The scholars specifically meant "conjoined twins" when they said "twins". The scholars may be anthropologists studying abnormal birth conditions.

Solution 3

> The scholars are architects discussing tall building structures. A, B and C are a sequence of 3 connected similar towers. A is the middle tower that is connected by bridges to both B and C, but B and C are not connected directly to each other. The scholars consider 2 towers to constitute *"twin towers"* only if they are right next to each other and perhaps also require them to be connected to each other directly through a bridge.

Answer (score 0):

Does 'twins' mean:

> Set membership. A twinned to B implies $A,B\in S$ for some S. So $A,B\in S$, $A,C\in T$ but no set in the universe contains B and C.
>
>  For example let $S=\{1,2\}, T=\{1,3\}$ and no other such sets. Then $A=1, B=2, C=3$ satisfy the questions criteria.

Answer (score -2):

It is Like This

> Let A = 1 , B = 2 , C = 3 B-A = 1 C-B = 1 hence they are twin but C-A
>  = 2 hence its not

kind of stupid logic:-P

Comment: But AB and AC are twins and BC arent... Maybe too stupid logic? :-P

Answer (score -2):

They said B and C are not twins.
But you thought that B and C are twins.
But according to them A and B or A and C are twins.
Over all from your response I get that:

> None of them are twins. They all just look similar.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I originally flagged this as rude/abusive, but instead I've edited out the offensive statement about Chinese people and retracted my flag. Please be aware of StackExchange's "Be Nice" policy.